# Pardot - cannot access visitor_id and visitor_id hash from javascript

Tags: pardot

After including the pd.js script pardot sets the visitor_id and the visitor_id-hash cookies only under the .pardot.com subdomain.

I would expect to find those cookies also under the subdomain of the website, as described [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.pardot_basics_cookies.htm&type=5).

Since they are not set under the website domain, the browser will prevent the javascript from reading those cookies for security reasons.

Why those cookies are set only under the .pardot.com domain?
Is there any other way to retrieve those values on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the First-Party cookie functionality, and if your Pardot Tracker domain and your website domain are the same (ignoring sub-domains), you should be OK using the correct tracker code.

Another alternative could be to place some javascript in a file that is loaded into Pardot as a File. Then you could reference that javascript with the go.pardot.com tracker domain.